# How to calculate number of post which have particular meta_key?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am using repeatable meta boxes what i want to achieve is display number of post which have particular meta key such as 
Country Pakistan
City Islamabad
Age 12
Age 12
Meta key "Age" is used in 2 posts.
No i want structure like Age in Post 2 , Islamabad in Post 1 , Pakistan in Post 1.

```
/**
* Display callback for the submenu page.
*/
function iif_register_submenu_form_details_callback() { 

$id = get_current_user_id();

    $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type'         => 'iff-info-forms',   
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'author'            => $id,
    'meta_query'        => array(
                        array(
                            'key'   => 'repeatable_fields',
                            //'value' => $user_data_new,
                            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
                        ))
     ) );
    //print_r($loop);
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    $info = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'repeatable_fields', true);

    if ( $info ) {
      //  echo '<strong>Emergency Contacts:</strong><br />';

        foreach ( $info as $emergency_contact_metas ) {
            echo '<strong>' . esc_html( $emergency_contact_metas['iif_label'] ) .'</strong> ' . esc_html( $emergency_contact_metas['iif_details'] ) . '<br />';
        }
    }

    endwhile;

}
```

OUTPUT SHOWING IS Below

Country Pakistan
City Islamabad
Age 12
Age 12

Comment: Hi I think this question is really simple and you haven't done sufficient research.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/231645/get-posts-for-custom-post-type-with-wp-query/231652
You can query anything from the DB in wordpress with wp_query.

Comment: no kindly read question properly i want the number of post which have particular meta box key.

Comment: Yes I know... So query by meta_key

Comment: Make a foreach - the increment a variable and echo that variable

Comment: for example right now i am showing  Age 12  two times how i count Age = 2 in particular post.

Comment: So in your foreach you must add an incrementer